# How to create Nuget package with C# and C++ libraries built with different options?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, nuget, nuget-package

There is a [project that wraps V8 engine into C# library](https://github.com/JavascriptNet/Javascript.Net). Its nuget package is broken and i'd like to fix it. Creating a package seems easy and there is documented way to pack different C# dlls for different .NET versions. However, i have no idea how to package .dll with C++ and C# code which could be built with different options:

- x64 or x86 and **not** "Any CPU"
- MS Visual C++ 2010/2012/2013
- debug or release
- .NET 4.0/...

I've found [this thread](https://npe.codeplex.com/discussions/462174) and it seems that one can use `.targets` file with MSBuild commands inside. Then i've read [in the docs](https://docs.nuget.org/Consume/Package-Restore) that MSBuild way is old and not recommended. So what should i do?

One more question is: if this package depends on MSVC++, how to specify this? How to let package consumer select a specific version of dll (built against MSVC++2010, 2012 or 2013)? I suppose it is not a good idea to package `msvcr*.dll`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at how the SQLite packages deploy their DLLs.  With the 2.x and earlier versions of NuGet you need to write some powershell code to inspect the version of Visual Studio and apply your changes to the project manually.

We are working towards a more elegant solution for this exact problem with the updates that are to be deployed in NuGet v3

Comment: Thanks, i'll take a look at SQLite.
More elegant solution - are you talking about  something like "pivots" in CoApp?